# Data still getting added in spite of TextBox validation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Well, I have a simple program that is writing to a Database. I am trying to add validation to the textbox like this,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         if (textBox1.Text.Length < -1)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Don't Leave this field blank!");
         }
    }
    catch
    {
         //todo
    }
}
```

and My save to database code,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = DAFFODILS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Book VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "')", con);
     con.Open();
     sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
     this.bookTableAdapter.Fill(this.booksDataSet.Book);
     MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
     this.Close();    
}
```

But still it is adding blank data to the database and strange thing is in the database I have not allowed null but still data is getting added. Any clues where I am wrong?

Comment: Can you add the save to database code also? Do you check there the textbox text length?

Comment: I will add the that code too. Just a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you stopping the database to add empty content. You are validating on the textbox_textchanged event which will only validate the text when someone enters the data. You need to put the validation on button1's click event like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Null String !!!!!!!!");
            return;
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = DAFFODILS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Book VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        this.bookTableAdapter.Fill(this.booksDataSet.Book);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
        this.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Whenever I am writing a text, it is constant showing the message box :/

Comment: You will need to check your TextBox's TextChangedEvent. That is causing the Messagebox to show. Either delete the code in that handler or fix it to just show the MessageBox when the TextBox is empty.

Answer (score 0):

An empty textbox.Text has zero byte length , not -1.
To be sure the textbox is not empty you should apply the Trim() to the current text
Also there is no need to catch an exception on this code.

Moreover, don't use the TextChanged event to validate the text box. 
There is the Validating event for this purpose. (Remember to set CauseValidation=True for the control)

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Don't Leave this field blank!"); 
             e.Cancel = true; 
        } 
}
```

of course you could move all the validation in the code where do you update the database

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{   
    if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Don't Leave this field blank!"); 
        return;
    } 

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
          "Server=DAFFODILS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;");      
    {
        SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Book " + 
                           "VALUES(@text1, @text2,@dtValue", con);      
        sql1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", textBox1.Text);
        sql1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text2", textBox2.Text);
        sql1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtValue", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
        con.Open();      
        sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();      
        this.bookTableAdapter.Fill(this.booksDataSet.Book);      
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");      
        this.Close();      

    }      
}
```

Comment: No change, still it is adding the code. Can you see my edited question again?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        //log
        return;
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = DAFFODILS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Book VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "')", con);
    con.Open();
    sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    this.bookTableAdapter.Fill(this.booksDataSet.Book);
    MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Whenever I am writing a text, it is constant showing the message box :/